# How can i solve this import pywinauto error?

Tags: python

I tried to import pywinauto and give to me this following error:
File "C:\Users\sbr7ca\Desktop\Projetos Python\Atualizando power bi\bi.py", line 4, in 
from pywinauto import Application

File "C:\Users\sbr7ca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pywinauto_*init*_.py", line 89, in 
from . import findwindows

File "C:\Users\sbr7ca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in 
from . import controls

File "C:\Users\sbr7ca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pywinauto\controls_*init*_.py", line 36, in 
from . import uiawrapper # register "uia" back-end (at the end of uiawrapper module)

File "C:\Users\sbr7ca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 42, in 
from .. import backend

File "C:\Users\sbr7ca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pywinauto\backend.py", line 35, in 
from .base_wrapper import BaseWrapper

File "C:\Users\sbr7ca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 44, in 
import win32ui

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32ui: Uma rotina de inicialização da biblioteca de vínculo dinâmico (DLL) falhou.

I tried to install a pywin32 compatible with my python version but doesn't worked.